# Linq expression - "variable" of type 'System.Data.DataRow' referenced from scope "" but it is not defined

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, tuples, expression

I am trying to dynamically build a lambda with a tuple at runtime using datarow fields to pass to a linq groupby.  I am getting an exception "variable" of type "System.Data.DataRow" referenced from scope ", but it is not defined.

```
MethodInfo fieldMI = typeof(DataRowExtensions).GetMethod("Field",new Type[] { typeof(DataRow), typeof(DataColumn) }.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
ParameterExpression fieldParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DataRow));

Type[] parameterTypes = new Type[fields.Count];
MethodCallExpression[] methodCallExpressions = new MethodCallExpression[fields.Count];

for(int i = 0; i < fields.Count; i++) {
parameterTypes[i] = typeof(string);
Expression dataElement = Expression.Constant(dc[i], typeof(DataColumn));
methodCallExpressions[i] = Expression.Call(null, fieldMI, new Expression[] { fieldParameter, dataElement});
}
var tupleTypeDefinition = typeof(Tuple).Assembly.GetType("System.Tuple`" = fields.Count);
var tupleType = tupleTypeDefinition.MakeGenericType(parameterTypes);
var constructor = tupleType.GetConstructor(parameterTypes);
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DataRow));
var body = Expression.New(constructor, methodCallExpressions);
var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<DataRow, object>>(body,param).Compile();
```

Comment: A DataRow must be associated with a DataTable.  You cannot call the datarow constructor.  Where is the DataTable in the query?

Comment: Sorry - I'm not really following - I'm not calling the datarow constructor that I can see... I'm calling the tuple constructor using string arguments that result from calling the Field method on the DataRow.  The lambda is receiving a datarow not a datatable.

Comment: Where is the table that the datarow came from?  You can't have a DataRow without the DataRow constructor being called.  So the DataRow is null and causing the error because the row did not come from a table.

Comment: Can you please suggest the needed change?

Comment: Where is the object that you are extracting data from?  Linq is a query (That is what the q stands for) so you need input data for the query.  Where is the data?You either need to use an existing DataTable or create a new DataTable before you can use DataRow.  If you do not have a DataTable than bind to a different type object.

Comment: I am using the lambda like this DataTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(func).  I created an expression for a where similarly with no reference to the datatable type and use it like DataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(func).  It works with no issue.  I can't even get this lambda to compile.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out - I created a new DataRow parameter (param) instead of using the same one created previously (fieldParameter).  Now it works.